# Changing axis size in ggscatter

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm plotting some correlations with `ggscatter` and trying to adjust the x and y axis sizes, so it doesn't cut out "more distant" points.

Example data:

```
structure(list(1_ALPHA = c(-0.0522375166935795, -0.209483222983504, 
-0.0503621796096076, -0.0409837898262994, 0.0704621877058586, 
-0.0420843104302165, -0.00221015920343636, -0.139149726246615, 
0.22501545896969, 0.0921854722788605, -0.0781357205382904, -0.0441796555501422, 
-0.0414139698401225, -0.951529967407252, 0.0396278543551783, 
0.227101983525108, -0.151554796690393, -0.454011358563869, -0.0444804626270398, 
0.0977618131764067), F_ALPHA = c(-0.092717695023124, 
-0.0802840347106722, -0.647481690113962, 0.156610668580935, -0.034265413101269, 
-0.0843928875283463, -0.132515736220666, 0.00342273712708447, 
0.230009118129893, -0.115297475665998, -0.0733757889425199, 0.115880509026173, 
0.0485888500933395, 0.105300281750034, -0.0426038706979207, -0.018221910187009, 
-0.0732434750859674, -0.230605854943992, 0.0203288610519503, 
-0.853494158957473)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've got the folowing:

```
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(data, x = "1_ALPHA", y = "F_ALPHA", 
          add = "reg.line", 
          add.params = list(color = "red", fill = "lightgrey"),
          conf.int = T, 
          color = "black", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "Task 1", ylab = "Task 2")
```

I tried adding the below but does absolutely nothing:

```
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(data, x = "1_ALPHA", y = "F_ALPHA", 
          add = "reg.line", 
          add.params = list(color = "red", fill = "lightgrey"),
          conf.int = T, 
          color = "black", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "Task 1", ylab = "Task 2") +
scale_x_continuous(labels = seq(-2:2), breaks = seq(-2:2))
```

Any suggestions?
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)

EDIT:
Added `limits = c(-2, 2)` but what I get is just a larger plot but cut off at the same place:

```
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(data, x = "1_ALPHA", y = "F_ALPHA", 
          add = "reg.line", 
          add.params = list(color = "red", fill = "lightgrey"),
          conf.int = T, 
          color = "black", 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "Task 1", ylab = "Task 2") +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2,2))
```

[image]

To illustrate better what I aim for, with a similar function it looks like that:

```
pairs(data[c(1,2)], 
      xlim = c(-2, 2),
      ylim = c(-2, 2),
      diag.panel = labels,
      lower.panel = panel,
      font.labels = 1, 
      cex.labels = 1.2,
      label.pos = 0.5,
      upper.panel = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `limits = c(-2, 2)` to `scale_x_continuous()`. Though it shouldn’t be cutting off points to begin with, unless ggpubr has some weird defaults.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Using your dput, all 20 points show up. What is it you are seeing?

Comment: Same here. Change 1_ALPHA to ALPHA_1 and try.

Comment: Hi there, basically, I've got a larger data set with a few hundred points. The scale of the graphs should the same for my variables. Maybe the reason I don't see some is because they overlap in the larger set. Still, I'd like to be able to adjust the scale, so it's not totally random for every plot.

Comment: TarJae, what do you mean? "1_ALPHA" is just a variable name.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Or maybe I do not get the core idea. According to naming conventions a variable name should not start with a number.

Comment: TarJae, the variable name in the data I work with is a longer one like "[TYPE_BRAIN_ACTIVITY]_[TASK]_[PROCESS]". I've shortened it for the purpose of this example, so it's not completely confusing. Nevermind, my issue is that the lines end where the points end, which is rather looking strange (compare with the last plot I added just now).

Comment: In that case I think you want to add the argument `fullrange = TRUE` to `ggscatter`.

Comment: Allan, thank you, adding it worked as intended!